# Flux initializing stores on reroute

Tags: javascript, reactjs, flux, react-router

So I've been getting in to Flux the last couple of days, and more specifically I have chosen the alt flux implementation to work around. Mostly because of they way it handles server side rendering, which I thought was very nice. I am also using React Router (1.0.0-beta3 for now)

I have a problem with where to initialize my stores with data. My application uses server side rendering, thus I can fetch initial data from the API when a request comes to my server, and depending on the path that the user has entered I can fetch different data. (Is this correct? Seems kinda odd to me, since the purpose of SSR is avoiding the "blank white screen" but now we have to wait for async callbacks before sending back the server rendered DOM?)

But what if my user clicks on the Navbar for example, changing the path in react router? How do I initialize a store with new appropriate data now? If i understand everything correctly, this will not trigger another request from the server. It will simply rerender on the client using the bundled javascript. What do I do in this situation?

Say for example that I have a ProjectsStore that on /projects contains all projects that a company has ever done, but on /company/projects it only contains the projects for that specific company. How would I go about changing the data in this store?

Comment: I don't think that's correct. Your JS bundle only includes your code and maybe the initial data. Subsequent requests for more data will have to go to the server again.

Comment: I did some testing and it seems that I get a request from the server whenever I change the route. So what I should do is populate the stores based on the route from the user at all times?

Comment: why not trigger an action that will fetch the results from the server on client actions ?

Comment: So one would fire an action like **ARRIVED_AT_COMPANY_PAGE** which would fetch the appropriate data and then tell the corresponding stores? I don't see why this wouldn't work, but it feels kind of cumbersome, and I feel there should be a way to define what data to gather when changing a route.

Comment: I may not be correct here, but it doesn't feel "clean" having to define actions in addition to changing the route.